# What is the true meaning of using SVD in finding null space?

Tags: matrices, svd

What is the true meaning of using SVD in finding null space? I mean why when lots of paper mention the null space,they will do SVD ? what can we know after we do SVD ?

For example : $\mathbf G \in R_r \times R_t $ , and $\mathbf W \in R_t \times R_r$,now i want $\mathbf W \mathbf G \mathbf W = 0$, and i know if $R_r > R_t$,the null space of $\mathbf G$ is $R_r - R_t$,then why should still do SVD to $\mathbf W \mathbf G = 0 ? $

Comment: A matrix has one zero singular value for each dimension in its nullspace, doesn't it? That sounds useful to me.

Comment: @Arthur Can you explain it in detail? because i still don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Do you know what a "singular value" is?

Comment: @Arthur well i know what is the singular matrix,but i don't know what is the singular value

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: OK! i know what the singular value is now,but i still don't understand  what does "A matrix has one zero singular value for each dimension in its nullspace" mean

Comment: Another cool consequence of using SVD rather than, say, Gaussian elimination, is that, for a numerical application (on a computer, say), you might find that some of the singular values that come out of your computer program are very small but non-zero, like 0.00005.  Depending on the application, you might look at this and decide, "this direction 'essentially' belongs to the null space".  In this sense, SVD is a more "numerically stable" way of deciding the dimensionality of your null space because you can assign a "tolerance" in the way I just described.

Answer (score 3):

This is an explanation of Arthur's comment: A matrix has a zero singular value for each dimension in it's nullspace.

Consider a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and assume we have its SVD:
$$
   A = U \Sigma V^T = [u_1\; \cdots \;u_m] \,
  \Sigma\,
   \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1^T \\
    \vdots \\
    v_n^T
   \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We have
$$
  A v_i = U \Sigma V^T v_i = U \Sigma e_i = U (\sigma_i e_i) = \sigma_i u_i.
$$
This equation gives the following: for every zero singular value, $Av_i = 0$ and thus $v_i \in \ker A$. On the other hand, for every non-zero singular value, $A v_i = \sigma_i u_i$ is not the zero vector. Since the $v_i$'s form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the number of zero singular values is equal to the dimension of the null space $\ker A$.